# Redux reducer is not returning the entire state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm new to **redux**,My problem is when i dispatch action, it is going to the reducer but the state is not updating.

> This is my initial state

```
   const initialState ={
    cart :[ ],
    Products:[
        {
            id:"1",
            title:"Realme 3 pro",
            image:{
                img1:"https://www.monotain.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/realme-5-pro.jpg",
                img2:"https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2019/smartphones/org/2019-05-20-product-7.jpg"
            },
           
            price:"10000",
            details:"Take photography a notch higher with the Realme 3 Pro as it comes with a 25 MP AI Selfie Camera and 16 MP + 5 MP Rear Camera with Sony IMX519 Sensor. The Qualcomm Snapdragon 710 AIE, multi-core AI Engine and Adreno 616 GPU redefine your smartphone experience.",
            seller:"Cloudtail India",
            quantity:"0"
    
    
        }
       
       
    
     ]
     
}
```

** This is my reducer which is handling  this action **

```
         case UPDATE_QUANTITY:
              
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cart:state.cart.map((product,i) =>
                    {
                        if(i === (action.product.id-1))
                       {
                           return{product.quantity = action.qty.toString()}
                         

                       }
                           return product
                       
                        
                    })
                }
```

Other reducers are working fine and returning correct state but when i dispatch this action,My state is not updating .If there is any improvement to be done on code .Please specify

Comment: You are not returning anything in map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return from map:

```
case UPDATE_QUANTITY:
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: state.cart.map((product) => {
      if (product.id === action.product.id) {
        return {...product, quantity: action.qty.toString()}
      }
      return product;
    })
  }
```

Comment: I tried but that didint workand by the way why did u use spread for product

Comment: What exactly didn't work? The object spread is there so the original one is not mutated, as doing that in Redux can produce undesired side-effects.

Comment: I have edited my code with yours but the same error is still present where the state is empty

Comment: The issue is most likely in some other parts of your code. Also updated the answer to match the product by id instead of the array index, which is more reliable.

Comment: Thanks @clarity ,your code worked perfectly fine without any errors but can u please explain me the code since i couldnt understand whats going on. why did u use return {...product, quantity: action.qty.toString()} and again after the if statement u used return product.Please explain the code .Thanks in advance